# how to select specific rows with values with \ without group by

Tags: sql, db2

```
cust_id | acc_type
--------------------
   1     |   L1
--------------------
   1     |   M1
--------------------
   1     |   O1
--------------------
   2     |   R1
--------------------
   3     |   S1
--------------------
```

Result needed is

```
 cust_id | acc_type
--------------------
   1     |   L1
--------------------
   1     |   M1
--------------------
```

i.e with single cust_id i need these two values. when i use group by i get all 3 that are mapped to 1. Please help me resolve this in db2\sql

Comment: Can you provide a sample query with results as well as the desired results?

Comment: Doesn't `where acc_type in ('L1', 'M1')` do what you want?

Comment: If you do need some arbitrary rows you should provide the business logic!

Comment: @Aaron: select * from table
where acc_type in ('L1', 'M1')
and cust_id in (
select cust_id from table t
group by cust_id
having count (acc_type) = 1);

Comment: Why did you try `group by`? As Gordon said, using `where acc_type in('L1', 'M1')` should give you those 2 results. If you also need to filter by cust_id you can add `And cust_id = 1`

Comment: @GordonLinoff but in real time that is fetching cust_id that have L1 and M1 with other acc_type. But in want cust_id that have L1 AND m1 combination alone

Comment: @Aaron i want cust_id that have L1 and M1 combination alone. In real time there are 3 or 4 combinations that need to fetched for single cust_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE cust_id IN (SELECT cust_id 
                  FROM yourTable 
                  WHERE acc_type in ('L1', 'M1')
                  GROUP BY cust_id 
                  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 )
```

if can have repeated `acc_type` then

```
                  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT acc_type ) = 2
```

Comment: DB2 SQL error: SQLcode: -199, sqlstate: 42601, sqlerrmc: where;??([concat || /microseconds microsecond seconds secondnull

Comment: I'm so embarrassed, I put the lines in the wrong order. Shame on me :(. Check again

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you would seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.acc_type = 'L1' and
       exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.cust_id = t.cust_id and t2.acc_type = 'M1')
      ) or
      (t.acc_type = 'M1' and
       exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.cust_id = t.cust_id and t2.acc_type = 'L1')
      ) ;
```

For this query, you want an index on `t(cust_id, acc_type)`.

Comment: problem is i have just given sample. I have multiple codes, i.e more than 2

Comment: @Harathi . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you asked.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, with more details, including sample data, desired results, and a good explanation of what you want.  Modifying this question can result in answers being invalidated; that draws down votes and hence is rude.